# Comma needed before "as does"?

Tags: british-english, commas, academic-writing

Should I write this without a comma:

> The evidence from this study suggests that stroke may impose a comparable risk on the survival of older patients as do heart attack due to the close resemblance of the two patient populations.

Or with a comma:

> The evidence from this study suggests that stroke may impose a comparable risk on older patients’ survival, as does heart attack due to the close resemblance of the two patient populations.

Edited: "fracture" changed to "patient"

Comment: Your example has errors and, as such, it is hard to say how best to punctuate.

Comment: Thanks for noting this! Could you please point these errors out?

Comment: I have edited the first part but you need to give context to justify "comparative" and "fracture population" - *fracture population* is particularly strange. I also think that trying to link heart attacks in the same sentence is doomed to failure.

Comment: Thanks! Edited accordingly.

Comment: This looks like Off Topic proofreading to me. And I'd say ***as do heart attacks*** (plural, not ***attack***) is effectively an ***optional, parenthetical*** element, that should be set off by commas ***both before and after***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With comma. "As" is acting like a subordinating conjunction.

Some questions though. Does the 'comparable risk' refer to something being talked about in the sentence before your quote, or does it refer to the heart attack. For example "[obesity does damage]. Stroke does comparable damage, as does a heart attack." Or is it trying to say 'stroke damage is comparable to heart damage'? If it's the later, rewording might make it clearer and make your 'as' irrelevant.

"evidence suggests that both strokes and heart attacks impose comparable risks on older patient's survival due to..."

But that changes your emphasis, so it depends on what's going on before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).